# Why ShellExecuteEx does not set value of SHELLEXECUTEINFO.hProcess?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Why does `SHELLEXECUTEINFO.hProcess` is still `NULL` after successfully launching an executable with ShellExecuteEx while if I launch that executable with `CreateProcess` `PROCESS_INFORMATION.hProcess` is set to correct handle of executable?

I have to launch that executable with using ShellExecuteEx because it has to be elevated. Executable that I'm launching is `winMain` application created by me.

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFOW shellExecuteInfo;
memset(&shellExecuteInfo, 0, sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFOW));
shellExecuteInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFOW);
shellExecuteInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
shellExecuteInfo.hwnd = NULL;
shellExecuteInfo.lpFile = pathToExe;
shellExecuteInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
shellExecuteInfo.nShow = SW_HIDE;
shellExecuteInfo.lpVerb = L"runas";
shellExecuteInfo.hInstApp = NULL;
shellExecuteInfo.lpParameters = NULL;
ShellExecuteExW(&shellExecuteInfo);
```

Comment: In C++, instead of the `memset` just do `SHELLEXECUTEINFOW shellExecuteInfo{};`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Or `SHELLEXECUTEINFOW shellExecuteInfo = {sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFOW)};` after checking that `cbSize` is the first field of the struct...

Comment: The question has `C` tag, I don't think `SHELLEXECUTEINFOW shellExecuteInfo{}` works.

Comment: You don't "have to" use `ShellExecuteEx` to get elevation. There is moniker-based COM interface that can do the job, and that `ShellExecuteEx` uses internally. But it's long ago, I don't remember the details.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: The original tag was C++. The comment says C++.

Comment: From the docs: "Note  ShellExecuteEx does not always return an hProcess, even if a process is launched as the result of the call. For example, an hProcess does not return when you use SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST to invoke IContextMenu."

Comment: See if [`CreateProcessElevated()`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19165/Vista-UAC-The-Definitive-Guide) can return a process handle for an elevated process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was that `SHELLEXECUTEINFO.lpFile` was equal to the path of symbolic  link which points to the executable. This results in usage of Dynamic data exchange.
MSDN says

> In some cases, such as when execution is satisfied through a DDE conversation, no handle will be returned.

So if you need to get handle of the process you either have to set `lpFile` to the actual path of executable or resolve the path of symbolic link.

It works perfectly fine with elevation using `lpVerb = "runas"`.

Comment: Not according to the question that was asked. That states clearly that `pathToExe` is supplied. You need to answer the question that was asked.